# Populate form so I can edit localStorage data

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I didn't want my first post on Stackoverflow to be a question but I'm new at coding and need a little help. I'm trying to populate my form fields with localStorage data so it can be edited. I've  been at this all day. Not sure how to properly post my code so here goes.

It keeps throwing the error of "cannot read property of "1". I did get the form to fill but it was filled with "[object HTMLInputElement]" Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {
    alert("Name Has Been Saved");
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#form").serializeArray();
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000001);

    var item = {};
    item.first = ["First:", $("#first").val()];
    item.last = ["Last:", $("#last").val()];

    $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(item));

    });

});

//Fill with data from localstorage to edit
function editItem(){
    var value = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
    var item = JSON.parse(value);

    $("#form").show(function () {
        $("#userDiv").hide(function () {
        });  
    });

    $("#first").val(item.first[1]);
    $("#last").val(item.last[1]);
}

});

});


function deleteItem() {
    var ask = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?");
    if (ask) {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.key);
        alert("Contact was deleted!!");
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        alert("Contact was NOT deleted.");
    }

}

$("#clear").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(localStorage.length === 0){
        alert("There Is No Info To Clear")
    }else{
        localStorage.clear();
        alert("All Names Have Been Deleted!");
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    }
});
});

});


<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">

    <form id="form">

        <label>First<input type="text" name="First" id="first"></label>
        <label>Last<input type="text" name="Last" id="last"></label><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Clear" id="clear"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Show" id="show"/>
        </form>
        <ul id="userDiv">
         <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">to form</a>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

Comment: At one point is the error thrown? Please edit your code to remove unnecessary things, such as alerts etc. It will make it easier for people to answer because they won't need to read through so much junk.

Comment: Your `$.each` loop doesn't make sense. You're repeatedly storing the same item, not the data you're looping over. And later when you get the data from local storage, you expect `.first` and `.last` to be arrays, but they're just strings.

Comment: It is thrown when I try to run the editItem function. I may have deleted too much code.

Comment: You've edited away the `saveItem()` code that my above comment referred to. :(

Comment: I reposted it. My save function seemed to be working fine. Are you saying that it's messing up my edit function?

Comment: I misread your code before. Why do you need the `["First", ...]` subarray, when you already have the value in the `item.first` property? It seems redundant.

Comment: Where does `this.key` come from when calling `editItem`?

Comment: my input field has a name that ="First". I thought I needed it. I'm still a noob. I'm copying pieces of old pure javascript code that I have.

Comment: any other suggestion?